# Are any subalgebras of the steenrod algebra isomorphic to the group algebra over for some group?

Tags: homotopy-theory, hopf-algebras

Heading says it all. Wondering if there are any subalgebras of the steenrod algebra which are isomorphic as hopf algebras to $\mathbb{F}_2{G}$ for some group $G$? In particular interest to me are the obvious subalgebras generated by certain $Sq^i$. Is May's book on algebraic steenrod operations a good place to look?

Comment: Isn't the Steenrod algebra graded connected? I think that implies there can't be any nontrivial grouplike elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to be a comment, but it is not a complete answer.

As @QiaochuYuan says, there are no nontrivial grouplike elements, so this cannot happen as Hopf algebras. You can ask instead which Hopf subalgebras of the mod 2 Steenrod algebra $A$ are isomorphic to group algebras as *algebras*. The starting place for that is the classification of Hopf subalgebras of $A$, originally due to Anderson and Davis, described in various places ([here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404977900135) for example).

I don't know of any good "recognition theorem" for group algebras: how to tell if a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra $B$ is isomorphic to $kG$ for some group $G$. So I don't know a complete answer to your question, and I don't know if anyone knows an answer. Some comments:

- the classification of Hopf subalgebras of $A$ includes a classification of those which are isomorphic (as algebras) to group algebras of elementary abelian 2-groups: the Hopf subalgebras which are exterior algebras. See the cited reference.
- If $A(n)$ is the Hopf subalgebra generated by $\mathrm{Sq}^i$ for $i \leq 2^n$, then $A(0)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2 C_2$, and I doubt that any of the others are isomorphic to group algebras. The smallest semidihedral group has order 16, and there is a nice description of their group algebras; they are called "semidihedral algebras." There is actually a semidihedral algebra of dimension 8 — not isomorphic to the group algebra of any group — and it is isomorphic to $A(1)$. (See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89327/the-semidihedral-group-of-order-16-and-ko and the paper by Crawley-Boevey cited there, for example.)
- The next case would be $A(2)$, which is 64-dimensional. I bet there are invariants of groups (of their cohomology, for example) which will rule out the possibility that $A(2) \cong \mathbb{F}_2 G$ for any group $G$ of order 64. The first cohomology group of $A(2)$ is a 3-dimensional vector space, and that should eliminate most of the possibilities, for instance.